# Apollo Client state management

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-federation

I have a situation where I need to save user input on multiple UI pages and then send accumulated data to some 3rd party backend service.

I wanted to understand if Apollo Client is capable of storing user input on each page in its cache and then dumping it to the backend server when needed? Is it the right way of doing things?

What are the requirements for my tech stack in this case?

Currently I have the following setup: react frontend -> graphql -> Java backend

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use localStorage for save data in local state, or Do you need save

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).